# Videos in UICollectionView iOS iPad Application

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview

I am currently working on an iOS iPad application in which I have a recording functionality through which I can record and save the video to the documents directory of the application. The videos are saved in mov format. My questions is, I want to show all the recorded videos of the documents directory in a UICollectionView and once the user clicks the video, it should play.  Can anyone please help me to achieve this task?I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://youtu.be/h1XOOCRrl04 or https://youtu.be/7QlaO7WxjGg